# Docker container stops (exited with code 0)

Tags: docker-compose

If i use this `docker-compose.yml up -d` - everything works. Container is running.

```
version: '3'

services:
  centos7:
    image: centos:7
    container_name: hw_8.1_centos7
    tty: true
    command: /bin/bash -c "yum -y update && yum -y install -y python3 && exec /bin/bash"
```

I understand that a Docker container runs a single command. The container will be running as long as that process the command started is running. Once the process is completed and exits then the container will stop.

But if i remove `tty: true` - and then re-run `docker-compose up -d` i will get: `exited with code 0`

I don't understand why it is happening.
I use this command `/bin/bash -c "yum -y update && yum -y install -y python3 && exec /bin/bash` and in the end i use `exec /bin/bash`. So when the container is up, there will be `update`, then `install python` and then `exec bash`
But, for some reason, container is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The command `/bin/bash -c "yum -y update && yum -y install -y python3 && exec /bin/bash"` or `/bin/bash/` in general will try to create an `interactive shell`, but since there is no [tty](https://itsfoss.com/what-is-tty-in-linux/#so-what-is-tty-in-linux), the shell is not created, respectively the creation of the shell fails, the command cannot be executed and the container will stop running because the compose file is "done" with running every command you defined.

`exited with code 0` means without error (from the containers standpoint).